# Coordinates of tangent points from a point outside a spheroid (ellispoid of revolution)

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, intersection-theory

The blue conics in the figure is an ellipse (it would be in a case a circle), that represents the tangency points, from the line drawn from the point $P$ to the ellipsoid surface in all direction, that means, it is the horizon of the point $P$.

My question:
How to calculate the coordinates in $x,y,z$ of a point $M$, that lies on the horizon, and it has a bearing (azimuth) $\theta$ from (true) North clockwise?

My input data are the coordinates of P in terms of cartesian coordinates $X_p,Y_p,Z_p$

Thanks for help and tips in advance

Please see figure of geogebra:
[image]

**ADD**:

$x = (N+hgt)*cos(lat)*cos(lon)$
$y = (N+hgt)*cos(lat)*sin(lon)$
$z = ((1-e^2)*N + hgt)*sin(lat)$

With $N = a/sqrt(1 - e^2*sin(lat)^2)$

$hgt:$ height above ellipsoid  surface along the normal.

Setting $hgt=0$, that yields the position of $Q$ bcz it has the same coordinates as $P$, just it lies on the surface

Comment: Hint: the plane in which the blue conic lies is the polar of $P$.

Comment: Do you want this angle measured in the plane of the blue curve or is it a “spherical” angle on the surface of the ellipsoid?

Comment: Also, where exactly does $O$ lie? Is it the center of the blue conic or is it some other projection of $P$ onto the conic’s plane or the ellipsoid’s surface?

Comment: @amd this point is $Q$ not $O$, it is on the ellipsoid's srurface, so it has the same geographic coordinates of $P$ with one exception, it has no elevation above ellipsoid surface, this angle $\theta$ is spherical angle $North,Q,M$ on the ellipsoid but excuse me I represented it as if it were in the plane $(North,Q,M)$, so it is really the azimuth due North clockwise, excuse me again

Comment: Sorry, but I still don’t understand exactly how $Q$ is related to $P$. Is the line through them normal to the surface, does it pass through the center of the ellipsoid, or something else entirely?

Comment: Yeah $Q$ and $P$ are lying on the normal, this normal doesnt pass always throught the center, bcz it's ellipsoid not a sphere, due eccentricity